# Class template argument deduction using function return type

Tags: c++, templates, ctad

I want to make a class with a template parameter and a function (also with a template parameter) that returns a class instance.
However, for shorter code, I want to omit template parameters when returning the result of class construction.
I have no clue how do I call this type of technique and if it is possible.

For a better description of my question, the code below is an example that I am ideally seeking.

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Class
{
public:
    Class()
    {
        // Construction  
    };
};

Class<int>
Function()
{
    return Class();
    // not Class<int>();
}

int main()
{
    Class<int> instance = Function();
}
```

Depending on how I apply this type of technique, I may also need to use multiple template parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.
Template types are concrete after compilation, unlike languages like `C#` where there's metadata so it can allow uncomplete generic types, `C++` doesn't.
Types like `Class<>` or `Class<int,>` are not possible.

You could do `Class<void>` and let template deduction fill the void (pun intended).
Or you could template the function itself:

```cpp
template <class TInner>
Class<TInner> Function()
{
    return Class<TInner>();
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to name the return type in the return statement itself, the following works:

```
Class<int>
Function()
{
    return {}; // Calls Class<int>::Class() ctor.
}
```

But if you need to create an instance of that class inside the function, I would recommend returning `auto`:

```
auto Function()
{
    Class<int> instance;
    //Do something with instance...
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an output parameter to the function:

```
template <class TInner>
void Function(Class<TInner>& r)
{
    r = Class<TInner>();
}
```

and call it:

```
int main()
{
    Class<int> instance
    Function(instance);
}
```